# could not resolve host name while setting up namevirtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I have been working on setting up namevirtualhosts on my centos 5 server. I have added all of the virtualhosts to my httpd.conf file and alos uncommented the namevirtualhost line.I also have my domain name pointing to the correct ip address. I keep getting these errors and cannot seem to figure out why.

```
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *:80/ -- ignoring!
[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *:80/ -- ignoring!
```

I have looked all over the place and at many tutorials but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

Instead of:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

..you have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80/
```

Since the port section isn't pure numbers, instead of seeing `*` as the host part, it thinks `*:80/` is a hostname (and `:80` is the implied default port, for a config of `*:80\:80`).

Fix that and you should be ok.